# How to search elements who contain any substring specified inside an strings array without risking app performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, performance, mongoose

Given the Schema:

```
const dummySchema= new Schema({
    title: { type: String},
    category: { type: String},
    delivery: { type: String},
    ...  
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Dummy', dummySchema);
```

and given the arrays:

```
var titleSplitedArray = ["word1","word2","word3","word4"...];
var categoriesArray = ["category1","category2","category3","category4"...];
var deliveryOptionsArray = ["delivery1","delivery2","delivery3","delivery4"...];
```

How can I search for all records (without getting duplicates) where `title`, `category`, `delivery`, contains any of these substrings defined inside `titleSplited`, `categoriesArray`, `deliveryOptionsArray` ?

This code is working fine:

```
results = await Promise.all(titleSplited.map((value) =>
    getRecordsByQuery({title: { $regex: new RegExp('\\b' + value.toLowerCase() + '\\b', 'i') } } )
));
```

However, I am executing the same `await Promise.all(titleSplited.map((value) => { // execute query //}))` I realized that with a large amount of records, let's say 100,000, I can't execute this code without having performance issues as I am executing at least 20 different queries (I have more search filter options for more properties inside my schema).

Now, given this performance problem I want to create an infinite scroll for displaying these records, however I have to limit the amount of records that I will receive after the execution of the query.
Is there a way to create a mongoose query for each search option, then add those queries inside a MasterQuery which will contain the rest and then just executing once this DB call, without getting duplicates and then limit the results for the implementation of pagination/infiniteScroll?
`category` and `delivery` are easy problems as they are a single word string so I can use `$in` operator, however how can I solve the title problem and the pagination one?
Something like:

```
var finalRecords = Post.find(
    {$and:[
        { "title": /*contains substring inside array*/ },
        { "category": /*contains substring inside array*/ },
        { "delivery": {$in: deliveryOptionsArray} },
    ]}
)
.sort( "title" ).removeDuplicates().limit(25);
```

Comment: something like: `new RegExp('\\b(?:' + titleSplited.sort(byLengthDesc).map(RegExp.escape).join('|').toLowerCase() + ')\\b', 'i')`

Comment: Why do I have to sort by descending length? could you explain the Regex please? Also thanks for the answer

Comment: because of the difference in what `/stack|flow|stackoverflow/` and `stackoverflow|stack|flow` would match, when they get a chance. The first RegExp  would match `stack` and `flow` the second one would match the whole word if possible or fall back to the substrings. But I guess this doesn't matter in this specific case, probably wrote it like that just out of habit

Comment: It looks like this could be achieved by pure RegExp and It also looks like you are a good RegExp writer, do you have any good resources for writing them?